# Is there a way to use list comprehension to cycle two lists with different lengths?

Tags: python

I'm sure this is out there but I couldn't find it. I have two sets of numbers one my_id = 1252,4587 and two label.tag = 12, 25, 63. What I am trying to do is cycle both, (I think using list comprehension).

I'm a novice programmer. I've tried some loops but not sure how to get this. 
note:
print my_id = 1252,4587
print label.tag =  12
                   25
                   63

```py
for x in label.tag
list = [(my_id, x[label.tag]) for x in label.tag]
```

I am trying to get the result of:
[('1252,4587', '12'),('1252,4587','25'),('1252,4587','63')]

Comment: not very clear what you want - since the result is pretty trivial with the  above. Do you want something like the following `('a', 'b')` and `('A', 'B', 'C')` becoming `[('a', 'A'),('a', 'B'), ('a', 'C'), ('b', 'A'), ('b', 'B'), ('b','C')]`

Answer (score 2):

To get your desired result:

```
[(my_id, x) for x in label.tag]
```

But that isn't looping over `my_id` so I'm not sure what you mean by the "cycle" part

Comment: This divides my label.tag value by integer. For example, label.tag = 12 and 45. But when I do this it gives me  [('1252,4587', '1'),('1252,4587','2),('1252,4587', '4'),('1252,4587','5)]. I would like it to give me this instead:  [('1252,4587', '12'),('1252,4587','45')]. Any ideas?